Multivariable analysis for an ordinal dependent variable
I am investigating the factors associated with self-perception of oral health. My dependent variable is self-perception of oral health, which is an ordinal variable measured on a 5-point Likert scale. I have seven independent variables, which are categorical and binary.
I attempted an ordinal logistic regression analysis, but the data did not meet the proportional odds assumption. Could you suggest an alternative multivariable analysis method to assess these associations?

It is crucial to select a good method for checking the proportional odds (PO) assumption.  Which method did you use?  Please note that the Bland test is very anti-conservative and that SAS should not have included it in PROC LOGISTIC.  It rejects PO too easily when PO is actually true.
I think the best way to think about PO is to ask the question are we better off assuming PO or not assuming it.  This article shows some ways to assess whether relaxing the PO assumption is helpful or harmful.  It can be harmful by overfitting / model instability from having too many parameters.  AIC is one helpful metric in deciding between a PO model and a relaxed-assumption model such as the partial PO model (which relaxes the PO assumption for a subset of the predictors) or a multinomial logistic model (which relaxes the PO assumption for all predictors).
For more resources or ordinal modeling see this.

Nice articles. One thing that seems to get much less coverage (and isn't related to the current question) is ordinal independent variables.

Very much agree.  The only solution I’ve seen is the R brms package which automatically and elegantly handles ordinal predictors if you are willing to assume monotonic effects on Y.

Thank you very much for your explanation.
